# Rails engine concerns autoload paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have some rails engine 'Core', and I have:

```
# core/app/models/core/concerns/user_helper.rb
module Core
 module UserHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
  # some methods
  end
 end
end

# core/app/models/core/user.rb
module Core
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Core::UserHelper
 end
end
```

however it says **uninitialized constant Core::UserHelper**. So it seems engine doesn't load its concerns by default, so I added it in the autoload paths

```
module Core
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Core::Engine.root}/app/models/core/concerns)
    isolate_namespace Core
  end
end
```

And now I end up this error: **Unable to autoload constant UserHelper, expected myapp/core/app/models/core/concerns/user_helper.rb to define it**

So what is wrong here? When I checked the guide http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html and it didn't have the concerns in concerns directory, but rather under lib/concerns and had all reference to concern using Core::Concerns::MyConcern, so is this where to put concerns in engine?

Thanks

**Edit**

Yury comment explained the issue, it seems that in rails engines concerns directory don't get any special treatment, and it is treated as a normal directory under models, so modules in it must be within Concerns namespace, and when including a concern, you have to include it with Concerns namesapace as well, if I understand right. I 'm surprised this is not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: i think the module should be named Core::Concerns::UserHelper, and it can stay in the `app/models/concerns` directory

Comment: seems this solved the problem, another problem raised but I don't think it is another problem, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 33):

The concern must reside inside the app/models|controllers/concerns/engine_name/concern_name.rb. This will autoload the concern.

To include the concern, include EngineName::ConcernName.

Comment: Is it possible to load a subclass? `app/models|controllers/concerns/engine_name/MODEL_NAME/concern_name.rb` for extra organization?

Comment: I tried that URL and it doesn't seem to load it. Perhaps one has to augment the autoloading config?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. Your mistake is that you are putting the `concerns` directory in the `app/{models|controllers}/core` directory, when it should be the other way round.

Instead of doing

`app/{models/controllers}/core/concerns/user_helper.rb`

change it to be

`app/{models/controllers}/concerns/core/user_helper.rb`

It took me a bit to figure out, because I intuitively thought it should also be under the `engine_name` directory.

Hope this helps.